# If The function $\phi$ satisfies the Laplace equation then what we can say about $\overrightarrow{\nabla} \phi$

Tags: real-analysis, vector-fields

If The function $\phi$ satisfies the Laplace equation i.e $\nabla^2\phi=0$  the what we can say about $\overrightarrow{\nabla} \phi$

> $1)$.it is solenoidal but not irrotational
>
> $2)$.it is both solenoidal and irrotational
>
> $3)$.it is neither solenoidal nor irrotational
>
> $4)$.it is Irrotational but not Solenoidal

The question in may book is very lenghty ,but i try to make it condense , i am not sure that i am missing important parts of this question.I have no idea about this question,I only know about the terms Laplace,irrotational and solenoidal but not at that extent so that i can solve this question.

Please help

Thank you.

Comment: You know its divergence is zero.. What can you conclude from that?

Comment: does the data provided is insufficient?